# How to update state based on checkbox status of being checked

Tags: reactjs

I have a bunch of checkboxes with the following markup

```
<input type='checkbox' data-id='123' data-label='abc' ref={checkboxRef} />
<input type='checkbox' data-id='456' data-label='xyz' ref={checkboxRef} />
```

And a state which is initially set as an empty array

```
const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([])
```

**What I want to do is update the state with an object of a checkbox's data based on whether it's checked or not. If checked, it's data is to be added to the state and if unchecked, remove it.**

Expected state after a checkbox is checked

```
[
  { id: '123', label: 'abc' }
]
```

I've used a ref for now to the input and getting the data of it but can't figure out how to go about updating the state.

```
const handleToggle = () => {
  setIsChecked(prevState => !isChecked)
  const id = checkboxRef.current.getAttribute('data-id')
  const label = checkboxRef.current.getAttribute('data-label')
}
```

Comment: so updating state is your problem?

Comment: Yeah. In a way that if a checkbox if checked it's data is to be added as an object to the state and if unchecked, the object already present in the state is to be removed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved it. Check it here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-fermi-f6bct

Full code hereby is

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
  const ref1 = React.createRef();
  const ref2 = React.createRef();

  const handleClick = (ref) => {
    const id = ref.current.getAttribute("data-id");
    const label = ref.current.getAttribute("data-label");
    if (contacts.map((e) => e.id).includes(id)) {
      setContacts(contacts.filter((e) => e.id !== id));
    } else {
      setContacts([...contacts, { id, label }]);
    }
    console.log(contacts);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        data-id="123"
        data-label="abc"
        ref={ref1}
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("hi");
          handleClick(ref1);
        }}
      />
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        data-id="456"
        data-label="xyz"
        ref={ref2}
        onClick={() => handleClick(ref2)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```